# where can I get windbg for windows 7 64bit without the whole sdk?

Tags: windows-7, windbg

I am looking for windbg.  Without the whole Windows SDK

I saw this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736250/getting-windbg-without-the-whole-wdk

But the accepted answer, from dave black, (since MS has updated the content), seems to just be for Windows 8, and seems to be more than just windbg. (I doubt windbg is 1GB+)

I tried the sdksetup.exe files  and it shows a suitcase.

[image]

And anyhow I don't even want the whole SDK.

And when I click that it just shows a suitcase

Then when it does seem to load, it doesn't offer just the SDK

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was mentioned in the Stack Overflow answer you referenced in your question, you can download the tools from [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365).

Once you've downloaded and run `sdksetup.exe`, waited for the suitcase screen to pass, you just need to click "Next" a couple of times.  You'll get to this screen:

[image: Feature Selection Screenshot]

From there you can deselect everything except "Debugging Tools for Windows"

Comment: thanks.  interestingly mine is 256.2MB  http://i.stack.imgur.com/QKl5A.png   I will go ahead and install it

Comment: If that much-linked page has a link to JUST the debugger **for Windows 7** (that's ***SEVEN***, as in the integer between 6 and 8), then it is very successfully hidden from ordinary mortals. As far as I can see, it skips straight from Windows 8 to Windows XP.

Comment: @Martha, sorry you weren't able to find what you were looking for.  On the page I linked to, toward the bottom there is a link to the [Windows 7 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279).

Comment: The debugger for Windows 8 (and the one for 10) is documented as being back-compatible to Windows 7. And in my experience (I use WinDbg a _lot_), it is. So it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

### Windbg for windows 7 - download

x86: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi

x64: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools_amd64/dbg_amd64.msi

### Windbg for windows 10 (WinDbg 10.0.18362.1) - download

x86: https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/2/42245968-6A79-4DA7-A5FB-08C0AD0AE661/windowssdk/Installers/X86%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x86_en-us.msi

x64: https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/2/42245968-6A79-4DA7-A5FB-08C0AD0AE661/windowssdk/Installers/X64%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x64_en-us.msi

### Windbg preview (WindbgX) from Microsoft Store

https://www.microsoft.com/store/p/windbg/9pgjgd53tn86

Source:
https://github.com/yanglr/advDotnetDebugging/blob/main/README.md