# Where can I get WinDbg for Windows **7** without a metric boatload of other stuff?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Where oh where do I find a tool, any tool, that's **FOR WINDOWS 7**, and would allow me to peek inside a minidump file?

[Every](https://superuser.com/questions/982644/where-can-i-get-windbg-for-windows-7-64bit-without-the-whole-sdk) [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-can-i-find-dumpchk-or-equivalent-for-windows/f66f1d5c-5ba6-4142-b739-d147810eb64d) on the internet sends you to this page:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit

Problem is, that page DOES ***NOT*** CONTAIN A LINK TO A STANDALONE DEBUGGER FOR WINDOWS 7. Really, it doesn't. Here are all the links it contains:

> WDK Insider Preview builds
>
> Learn more about what's new in driver development
>
> Get Visual Studio Express for Desktop
>   Get Visual Studio Community 2015
>   Get Visual Studio Professional 2015
>   Get Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
>
> Install Window SDK for Windows 10, version 1703 *[love the typo, btw]*
>   Install WDK for Windows 10, version 1703
>
> Install the EWDK 1703
>   Learn more about the EWDK 1703
>
> GitHub
>   GitHub Extension for Visual Studio
>   Learn more about what's new for driver samples
>   Known issues for Hardware Dev kits and tools
>
> Get Visual Studio Express for Desktop
>   Get Visual Studio Community 2015
>   Get Visual Studio Professional 2015
>   Get Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
>
> Install the WDK for Windows 10, version 1607
>   Install the EWDK 1607
>
> Download Visual Studio 2013
>   Download WDK 8.1 Update
>   Download the WDK 8.1 Update Test Pack
>   Get driver samples for Windows 8.1
>
> Visual Studio Professional 2012
>   Visual Studio Ultimate
>   Download WDK 8
>   Download the WDK 8 redistributable components
>   Get driver samples for Windows 8
>
> Get (WinDbg) as part of Windows 8.1 SDK
>   Learn more and prepare for remote debugging
>   Download the Remote Debugging client
>
> Download WDK 7.1.0 *[per the description, this is for developing drivers for Windows XP or Windows Server 2003]*
>   support for the Windows SDK
>   Get the standalone debugging tools for Windows XP as part of Windows 7 SDK *[so close, yet so far: where are the standalone debugging tools for Windows ***7***?]*

## If one of those is supposed to be for Windows 7, that's a fact known only to some insider club that I'm not a member of.

Help? And if you answer with a link to that page (or close this as a duplicate of a question where the answers all just point to that page), I will curse you to all eternity.

Comment: have you tried the win10 sdk installer to get the debugger? does this work?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit

ha ha just kidding.  Try these:

[WinDbg 32-bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi)

Upvote [Wu Yongzheng's answer to Niall Connaughton's question: "Getting windbg without the whole WDK?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19443243/4411648) if that was helpful.

I do believe that I first (publicly) documented that well before Windows 10's release, and likely before Windows 8's release.  So hopefully that works out perfect for you.  The URL also contains a GUID, so I find it unlikely that Microsoft would distribute an updated file at that URL.

While I'm at it, here's some other hyperlinks I documented back in the day.

Here is a downloader:
https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/winsdk_web.exe

Again, that has a GUID, so likely hasn't been updated.

At the time of this writing, I haven't checked how much the following resources may have been updated to reflect Windows 10.  All I do know is that I documented this stuff a while ago.  So the following may or may not be as helpful for you as the above resources.

Found from https://www.microsoft.com/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279 which may just redirect to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279 which was found from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit

[Get Debugging Tools for Windows (WinDbg) (from the SDK)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=536682)

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg

Answer (score 1):

Run the [Windows 10 SDK setup](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and only select the `Debugging Tools for Windows`

[image]

and nothing else. Here you only need to download 200MBs.

Comment: **Note:** All debugger versions released after Windows 7 are back-compatible to at least Windows 7. So please don't complain "but that's for 10! I need 7!" It's fine.

Comment: @RickBrant which discussion? Was it deleted?

Comment: I was mostly addressing the OP, who is apparently under the misapprehension that WinDbg that is specifically and only for Windows 7 is what's required. Maybe I should have posted it as a comment to the OQ.

Answer (score 0):

### Windbg for windows 7 - download

x86: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools/dbg_x86.msi

x64: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/A/A6AC035D-DA3F-4F0C-ADA4-37C8E5D34E3D/setup/WinSDKDebuggingTools_amd64/dbg_amd64.msi

### Windbg for windows 10 (WinDbg 10.0.18362.1) - download

x86: https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/2/42245968-6A79-4DA7-A5FB-08C0AD0AE661/windowssdk/Installers/X86%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x86_en-us.msi

x64: https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/2/42245968-6A79-4DA7-A5FB-08C0AD0AE661/windowssdk/Installers/X64%20Debuggers%20And%20Tools-x64_en-us.msi

### Windbg preview (WindbgX) from Microsoft Store

https://www.microsoft.com/store/p/windbg/9pgjgd53tn86

Source:
https://github.com/yanglr/advDotnetDebugging/blob/main/README.md

FYI.